# Translating from SQL to R (concat and inner joins)

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.name,' ', a.surname) as "Deluxe drivers", m.producer, m.model
from employer a
INNER JOIN Driver s on s.iddriver=a.idemployer
INNER JOIN Taxi t ON t.idtaxi=s.idtaxi
INNER JOIN Model m ON m.idmodelcar=t.idmodelcar
WHERE m.producer IN ('Audi','Skoda','Honda','Hyundai') AND m.year>2010
GROUP BY a.name, a.surname, m.producer, m.model
ORDER BY 2,3
```

So this is pretty much a basic SQL query but I need to translate it to R and I have some difficulties. Also, I am not sure if there is a function like CONCAT that can basically unite 2 different columns into one so the name and surname don't appear separately.

Can anyone assist me, please?

Comment: Looks like your query does what you seems to expect. CONCAT(a.name,' ', a.surname) will show  "name surname" in the colomn "Deluxe drivers"

Answer (score 1):

When asking a question you should provide your data in a reproducible format, this makes it easier for us to help. I will give you a guideline of the functions I think can help you:

```
employer$deluxedrivers <- paste(name, surname, sep = ")
%in%
dplyr::group_by()
dplyr::order_by()
dplyr::filter()
merge()
```

Hope this helps you!

Also, if you want to use SQL in R there is a package called `sqldf` that let you do it!

Comment: Thanks, mate! I know that package but I've been reprimanded for using it before so I need to stay clear from it for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using only functions in base R.

The `paste()` function has the same action as `CONCAT`.  The `merge()` function has the same action as the `JOIN` statements--you will probably find it easiest to merge the data frames before selecting rows and columns.  The `%in%` operator has the same action as the `IN` expression.

You don't need a GROUP BY clause because you're not using an aggregate function.

The `sqldf` package would allow you to apply a SQL statement to the merged data frame, which may shorten the R learning curve.